# Are DataSets Returned from Web Services Cross Platform Interoperable?

Tags: web-services, soap, dataset

I am creating a web service in Visual Studio 2010. If it returns a DataSet (strongly typed), can someone from another platform access this endpoint and use the XML as needed, or will it look like garbage to them?

What are my alternatives?

EDIT: what if I returned a DataTable? I have read microsoft recommending against this in favor of DataSet for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cross-platform coders will still be able to read the XML, but it is not the best option.  [Scott Hanselman says](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=d88f7539-10d8-4697-8c6e-1badb08bb3f5):

> Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World

Here is the XML produced for  simple DataSet containing 1 table, with 2 columns and two records:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>hello</Column1>
    <Column2>world</Column2>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>hello</Column1>
    <Column2>greg</Column2>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Your cross-platform coders will need to parse the XML, which can become very cumbersome, especially if the data is complex.

DataSets are really about representing the Database - in a well designed, layered application, they should only be used in the Data Access Layer.  They should then be morphed into strongly-typed domain/model objects, which know nothing about databases.

A much better option is to use custom objects.  There is an example for how to do this on Ryan Farleys [blog](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/26/737.aspx).

**The main advantages of using custom objects are:**

1. They are fully interoperable.
2. They are strongly typed.
3. The consumer is not responsible for parsing/deserializing XML.
4. Separation of concerns between data storage and consumer.

**Side-note:**
I should point out that web-services are becoming out-dated.  If you're creating a new web service you really should use WCF.  It takes some learning but it's a much richer and more flexible platform.

Comment: That XML there seems about like I would expect, can you explain what you mean by custom objects please (and what advantage it would provide)?